# React - reset state to empty array if more than 2 items selected

Tags: reactjs, usecallback

I'd like to reset my selectedDogs state to 0 if more than 2 dogs are selected. How can I do this? At the moment, the array just keeps growing past 2. If 2 dogs are selected, I'd like to trigger an action (e.g. write to console or something).

```
  const [selectedDogs, setSelectedDogs] = useState<IDog[]>([]);

  const updateSelectedDogs = useCallback(
    async (dog: IDog) => {
      if (selectedDog.length > 2) {
        setSelectedDogs([]);
      }
      const updatedSelectedDogs = [...selectedDogs];
      updatedSelectedDogs.push(dog);
      setSelectedDogs(updatedSelectedDogs);
    },
    [selectedDogs],
  );

  ...

  <button onClick={() => {updateSelectedDogs(dog).then();}}>Click ({selectedDogs.length})</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution (if the further code is not needed in the case >2 length), is to return after the setState

```js
  const updateSelectedDogs = useCallback(
    async (dog: IDog) => {
      if (selectedDog.length > 2) {
        return setSelectedDogs([]);
      }
      const updatedSelectedDogs = [...selectedDogs];
      updatedSelectedDogs.push(dog);
      setSelectedDogs(updatedSelectedDogs);
    },
    [selectedDogs],
  );
```

This issue likely lies in setting the state of selectedDogs to an empty array and then accessing the array in the next line, by which point the setState (which functions asynchronously) might not have been completed, thus returning an old state in the spread on the following line.